# How to change the value between <a><a/> python lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

So i have a xml file in which I want to store a string.

ive tried everything i found on other questions, even having the value stored in an attribute

Here is my .xml file:

```
<a>value<a/>
```

I need to change 'value' with user input.

```
def log(self):
    self.tree = etree.fromstring('info.xml')
    self.sh = self.tree.find('a')
    self.inusr = input('Your new username: ')
    self.sh.set('user', self.inusr)
```

The problem with this try is that it changes only the user attribute value. To fix it I tried removing the attribute in the last line but it did not work.

Comment: Could you post the things you tried, and describe what were the unexpected results?

Comment: your xml is not well formed..

Comment: this xml is just for the purpose of this question. feel free to edit it. my point is to change 'value' into something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute `text` may be helpful:
my.xml:

```
<data>
    <a>value1</a>
    <a>value2</a>
</data>
```

main.py:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('my.xml')
sh_list = tree.findall('a')
inusr = input('Your new username: ')
for sh in sh_list:
        sh.text = inusr
tree.write('my.xml')
```

input:

```
myname
```

altered my.xml:

```
<data>
    <a>myname</a>
    <a>myname</a>
</data>
```